# I'm looking for the translation of the Dharmaskanda Sutra

Tags: sutras

Where can I get the English translation of the Dharmaskanda Sutra or at least the original text?

Comment: Are you sure with the name of the sutra.

Comment: Yes, it's Dharmaskanda or Dharmaskandha.

Comment: Do you mean the Dharma-skanda-shastra? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmaskandha

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Abhidharmadharmaskandhapādaśāstra, the Sanskrit fragments have been discussed in English in J. Takasaki, [Remarks on the Sanskrit Fragments of the Abhidharmadharmaskandhapādaśāstra.](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ibk1952/13/1/13_1_411/_pdf) JIBS 13,1 (1965) 411-403 <33-41>.